# How to display fluentvalidation error message on view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

I've a fluent validator as below

```
[Validator(typeof(testvalidator))]
public class test
{
   .....
}

 public class testvalidator: AbstractValidator<test>
 {
     public testvalidator()
     {
        Custom(testvalidationmethod);
     }
     public ValidationFailure testvalidationmethod(test t)
     {
        return ValidationFailure("","error occurred in test validation method ");

     }

 }
```

Usage

```
  testvalidator tv = new testvalidator();
  var result =tv.(test);
```

I can see the error message in the `result.Errors`. But I want to display the error message on the view. I tried `Html.ValidationSummary()` with `true` and `false`. But didn't work. What need to be done to display on the view? I was reading [tutorial](https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CreatingAValidator). But it shows how to display on the `console`, which is hardly required in the real application. How do I make it work?

Comment: To avoid coding efforts, I think you can add the following line to the Application_Start() method global.axcs file to register the FV configuration: FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure();

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a method named `AddToModelState`, which needs to be called to add errors to `ModelState`. After that errors started showing up in the view.

Usage

```
public ActionResult DoSomething() {
  var customer = new Customer();
  var validator = new CustomerValidator();
  var results = validator.Validate(customer);

 results.AddToModelState(ModelState, null);
 return View();
}
```

Source of above [fluentvalidation on github](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/wiki/h.-MVC). Look at Manual Validations.

Comment: Excellent solution. Thanks. I use attribute [Validator(typeof(MyViewModelValidator))] for my model class MyViewModel, but the validation state of ModelState fails to validate, and it always return true in a POST action. I don't know why that fails. So I have to use Manual Validations.

Comment: I am trying to learn fluent validation.  if (!result.IsValid)
            {
                result.AddToModelState(this.ModelState);
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            } I get the error in a good format but I lost access to "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-1a68c87bda2ffb8de50b7d2888b32d02-94d30c7679aec10b-00"